# Hide/show list after nth item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two list :

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
<a href="#" class="btn-more"><img src="../img/more.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
<a href="#" class="btn-more"><img src="../img/more.png"></a>
</div>
```

I would like to show the three first item. And show/hide (toggle) the other items when I click on `.btn-more`

I try something with dynamic number :

```
$('.list ul').each(function(){
    var max = 2;

    if ($(this).find("li").length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide()
    }
});
```

That's work but I don't know where to add my code for my button to show/hide the others items.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with CSS and just toggle a class with jquery (*that controls the show/hide*)

```js
$('.list .btn-more').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.list').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.list li:nth-child(n+3){display:none;}
.list.open li:nth-child(n+3){display:list-item;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="btn-more">
    <img src="../img/more.png">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="btn-more">
    <img src="../img/more.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I would like to know if this CSS is compatible with IE9 ?

Comment: @Xroad ofcourse. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3  (*and click **show all** to see full support*)

Answer (score 2):

You could hide all the lower than `2` li's in all the lists using  :

```
$('.list ul').each(function(){
    $('li:lt(2)', this).hide();
});
```

Then you could add click event to the button class and show all the related li's like :

```
$('.btn-more').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.list').find('ul li').show(); //Show all
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
show_less();

$('.btn-more').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var parent = $(this).closest('.list');

  if(parent.find('li:visible').length==3){
    $('img', this).attr('src','http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/arrow-icon-clip-art-file-down-arrow-icon-png-balin-icon-arrow-right--32.png');

    parent.find('ul li').show(); //Show all
  }else{
    $('img', this).attr('src','http://payload350.cargocollective.com/1/6/200896/9316237/down-arrow.png');
    show_less();
  }
})

function show_less(){
  $('.list ul').each(function(){
    $('li:gt(2)', this).hide();
  });
}
```

```css
img{
  width:25px;
  height:25px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="btn-more"><img src='http://payload350.cargocollective.com/1/6/200896/9316237/down-arrow.png' /></a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="btn-more"><img src='http://payload350.cargocollective.com/1/6/200896/9316237/down-arrow.png' /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't hide again after

Comment: Where you want to hide? With the same button?

Comment: Yes with the same button. A toggle system :-)

Comment: Ahaha great but my button is a image. A sort of "plus"

Comment: You could toggle the images if you've plus and minus pictures just toggle the `src` instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:gt()` selector of JQuery. Demo:

```js
$("li:nth-of-type(1n+4)").hide();


$(".btn-more").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".list").find("ul>li:gt(2)").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="btn-more">
    <img src="../img/more.png">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="btn-more">
    <img src="../img/more.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't hide again after

Comment: I have a conflict with the other list

Comment: @Xroad Ok, fixed that. Usually you would use some identifiers for each list/button but this works in general.